# Tika parser is not parsing all the file

Tags: pdf, apache-tika

I have a pdf file which is 122 pages. When I parse it using `Tika` (version 1.17), it doesn't return the whole text in the returned `string`.

I use the following simple code to get the text:

```
    String content = new Tika().parseToString(file);
```

The text that I get with this code, ends at around page 118. That is, the last pages are ignored.

Comment: Do the last few pages actually contain "plain text", or are they a scanned image with text shown on it?

Comment: @Gagravarr They have both plain text and images and the strange thing is that the returned text ends at the middle of a sentence!

Comment: What happens if you set a longer [maximum string length on your Tika object](https://tika.apache.org/1.16/api/org/apache/tika/Tika.html#setMaxStringLength-int-) ?

Comment: @Gagravarr It worked. Thanks. I set it to Integer.MAX_VALUE. Would you like to write it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Promoting a comment to an answer...

Apache Tika will by default set a maximum size of text it'll allow a parser to generate, to avoid accidentally swamping a user. In your case, it looks like you're hitting that limit when you really do want more!

As a user of the Tika facade helper class, you just need to call [Tika.setMaxStringLength(int)](https://tika.apache.org/1.16/api/org/apache/tika/Tika.html#setMaxStringLength-int-) with a higher limit, or `-1` just to disable the limits entirely

If you're using the Tika parser classes directly, then you should set a higher write limit (or `-1`) to your content handler, eg [BodyContentHandler(int writeLimit)](https://tika.apache.org/1.17/api/org/apache/tika/sax/BodyContentHandler.html#BodyContentHandler-int-)